# Tensorflow custom gradient with different dimension of input and output

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient

I try to define new op and gradient for Tensorflow.
I found the following link:
https://gist.github.com/harpone/3453185b41d8d985356cbe5e57d67342

It works fine, as long the input dimension equals to the output dimension.
I want to send 2 parameters of size (1,) and get op of size N=(65536,) for each and gradient of the same size N=(65536,) for each.

my input is: x (1,) ,y (1,)

output:

```
op N=(65536,)

grad of x: N=(65536,)

grad of y: N=(65536,)
```

or 
input par (2,)
output grad N=(65536,2)

in the training, I will use reduce_sum, so I will get 2 numbers (as the parameters) and the gradient descent should works correctly.

But it doesn't work and I get the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tfTmp.py", line 97, in <module>
    gr = tf.gradients(z, [x,y])
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py", line 532, in gradients
    gate_gradients, aggregation_method, stop_gradients)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py", line 734, in _GradientsHelper
    (op.name, i, t_in.shape, in_grad.shape))
ValueError: Incompatible shapes between op input and calculated input gradient.  Forward operation: myOp.  Input index: 0. Original input shape: (1,).  Calculated input gradient shape: (65536,)
```

My code:

```
import...
def my_op(x,y):
    op_output=getOutput(x,y) # size of N=(65536,)
    return op_output

def callGrad(op,grad):
    x = op.input[0]
    y = op.input[1]
    Gx=calculateGradx(x,y); # size of N=(65536,);
    Gy=calculateGrady(x,y); # size of N=(65536,);

    return Gx,Gy

def pyfunc(func,inp,Tout,stateful=True,name=None,grad=None)
    rnd_name = 'PyFuncGrad' + str(np.random.randint(0, 1E+8))

    tf.RegisterGradient(rnd_name)(grad)
    g= tf.get_default_graph()
    with g.gradient_override_map({"PyFuc": rnd_name});
        return tf.py_func(func, inp, Tout, stateful=stateful, name=name)

from tensorflow.python.framework import ops

def tf_ops(x,y, name=None)
    with ops.name_scope(name, "myOp", [x,y]) as name:
        z = py_func(my_op,

[x,y],[tf.float32],name=name,grad=callGrad);
            return z[0];

with tf.Session() as sess:
    N=1; # for N=65536 it works but I want only one parameter
    x=tf.constant(np.ones(N)); 
    y=tf.constant(np.ones(N));

    z=tf_op(x,y);
    gr=tf.gradients(z,[x,y]);

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer();
    sess.run(init)

    print(x.eval(), y.eval(),z.eval(), gr[0].eval(), gr[1].eval())
```

important note: I don't want to do the reduce_sum in the gradient because that I will use the Automatic differentation, so I want to get for the following cost function:
sum((ref-OP(x,y))^2)

the gradient 
-2 * sum((ref-OP(x,y)) * dOp/dx)) , -2 * sum((ref-OP(x,y)) * dOp/dy))

so dOp/dx should be the same as Op , i.e N=(65536,)